# Can not get all image data after file select using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have an issue while using `ng-file-upload` from angular.js for file uploading.When user is selecting multiple file at a time and after selection in `ngf-select` function i am getting only one file data.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.bannerimage.$touched && billdata.bannerimage.$invalid }">
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="bannerimage"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}"  custom-on-change="uploadFile" required="required" ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);"  ngf-multiple="true">
</div>
```

From the above code suppose user clicked on choose file button and when file dialog opened user selected 3 files at a time.after selecting all files inside `onFileSelect` function user is getting only one file blob data.My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
         if($files!=null){
         var data={'image':$files};
         $scope.allFiles.push(data);
         console.log('file details',$scope.allFiles,data);
         }

    }
```

Its ok for one after another selection process but at a time selecting multiple file process is not happening.Here i need both condition should work.If user selected multiple file at a time inside `onFileSelect` function all files should display in console message.Please help me.

Comment: `onFileSelect($files);` instead of `onFileSelect($file);`

Comment: @danial : I did as per you but its not coming...

Comment: And don't push them into allFiles or use `concat` instead of push.